# Using Stripe Checkout in a .net MVC Application

Tags: c#, .net, stripe-payments

I'm trying to use Stripe Checkout to build my first MVC application, using the steps directly from Stripe found here - https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/aspnet

When I try and compile after following the steps, I receive the following errors...

**Startup.cs**

Error   CS0103  The name 'StripeConfiguration' does not exist in the current context

**HomeController.cs**

Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'ChargeCreateOptions' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'CustomerCreateOptions' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'ChargeService' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'CustomerService' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have already ensured I have the most recent Stripe Package using Tools>NuGet Package Manager>Manage NuGet Package for Solution.

**HomeController.cs code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using StripeCheckoutNPP.Models;

namespace StripeCheckoutNPP.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller

    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult About()
        {
            ViewData["Message"] = "Your application description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewData["Message"] = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
        public IActionResult Charge(string stripeEmail, string stripeToken)
        {
            var customers = new CustomerService();
            var charges = new ChargeService();

            var customer = customers.Create(new CustomerCreateOptions
            {
                Email = stripeEmail,
                SourceToken = stripeToken
            });

            var charge = charges.Create(new ChargeCreateOptions
            {
                Amount = 500,
                Description = "Sample Charge",
                Currency = "usd",
                CustomerId = customer.Id
            });

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace StripeCheckoutNPP
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });


            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            StripeConfiguration.SetApiKey(Configuration.GetSection("Stripe")["SecretKey"]);
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the namespace for `StripeConfiguration` and did you include it with a `using` for the Startup.cs?

Comment: have you run the `dotnet restore` command?

Comment: @Jmesolomon I ran the dotnet restore command after I ran "dotnet new mvc" and dded the stripe.net package using "dotnet add package Stripe.net"

Comment: @Jasen would the namespace be StripeCheckoutNPP, the name of the project? Would I add "Using StripeCheckoutNpp" to the top of the Startup.cs file?

namespace StripeCheckoutNPP
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
            StripeConfiguration.SetApiKey(Configuration.GetSection("Stripe")["SecretKey"]);

        }

Comment: @LAUSVUITTON I noticed in your `Startup.cs` you don't have the `StripeConfiguration.SetApiKey(Configuration.GetSection("Stripe")["SecretKey"]);` line of code inside the `Configure` method

Comment: @jmesolomonthank you, will take another look at it and update code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2017 added .NET Core->ASP.NET Core Web Application named StripeCheckoutNPP.  Version ASP.NET Core 2.2.  Chose Web Application (Model-View-Controller).  Unchecked Configure for HTTPS.  Rebuilt project solution.  Added Stripe.Net.  stripe.net https://dashboard.stripe.com/login?redirect=%2Faccount%2Fapikeys
added my secretkey and publishkey to appsettings.json

Mine works even after the last answer post - doing your way.

It seems you are not nugeting correctly, so that the stripe namespaces and classes are not getting properly referenced.

I installed free JustDecompile, and saw that all your errors, for classes
StripeConfiguration
ChargeCreateOptions
CustomerCreateOptions
ChargeService
CustomerService
Are in the Stripe.net.dll

[image]

Comment: I have tried using the standard microsoft command line, Manage Nuget Packages for Solution to uninstall and reinstall, and finally the package manager console.

Package manager console is returning: PM> Install-Package Stripe.net
Restoring packages for C:\Users\Aadvisor Marketing\Desktop\StripeCheckoutNPP\StripeCheckoutNPP.csproj...
Installing NuGet package Stripe.net 24.5.0.
Committing restore...
Assets file has not changed. Skipping assets file writing. Path: 
Restore completed in 1.61 sec for C:\Users\xxxx
Executing nuget actions took 621.95 ms
Time Elapsed: 00:00:03.6724080
PM>

Comment: You are creating a Core project correct?  Maybe you should use core 2.2.  Can you just  make a nuget to current version Stripe.net 24.5?

Comment: Instead of using the command line, you can follow my directions.  Also, you did register with Stripe?  You need the secretkey and  publishkey into appsettings.json that are proprietary to you.

Comment: @LAUSVUITTON I added an image.

Answer (score 0):

According to the instruction, your **Configure** method should be

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        StripeConfiguration.SetApiKey(Configuration.GetSection("Stripe")["SecretKey"]); 
        // the rest of the code....
    }
```

Currently, you have the `StripeConfiguration.SetApiKey()` in the constructor